# Превращение файла питона в exe

Tags: python, exe

Создал парсер на питоне, вот код

```
import time

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from requests.exceptions import TooManyRedirects
import datetime
import csv

HEADERS = {"user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64)"
                         " AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) "
                         "Chrome/87.0.4280.141"
                         " Safari/537.36"
                         " OPR/73.0.3856.427","accept": "*/*"
}
FILE = "result.csv"
file = open("Links.csv","r")
rows = file.readlines()
file.close()
count = []

def get_html (url):
    try:
        r = requests.get(url,headers=HEADERS)
        return r
    except TooManyRedirects:
        pass

def get_content(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")
    try:
        items = soup.find("span", class_="_18lf326a").get_text()
        count.append({"Ссылка":line,"Кол-во ТТ":items,"Дата":datetime.datetime.today().strftime("%d.%m.%Y"),"Площадка":"2гис"})
    except:
        count.append({"Ссылка":line,"Кол-во ТТ":0,"Дата":datetime.datetime.today().strftime("%d.%m.%Y"),"Площадка":"2гис"})
    return count

def save_file(items,path):
    with open(path,"a+",newline='') as file:
        writer = csv.writer(file,delimiter=";")
        for item in items:
            writer.writerow([item["Ссылка"], item["Кол-во ТТ"], item["Дата"], item["Площадка"]])

def parse():
    i=0
    for row in rows:
        i=i+1
        print(f'Пробую парсить {i} ссылку из '+str(len(rows))+" ссылок")
        global line
        line = row.replace("\n", "")
        html = get_html(line)
        try:
            get_content(html.text)
        except:
            pass
    save_file(count, FILE)

parse()
```

Когда преобразовал файл в .exe получаю ошибку ( когда запускаю преобразованный файл в exe )

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: "преобразовал файл в .exe" - тут нужны подробности: чем, на какой машине, где запускается и т.д...

Comment: pyinstaller, на ноутбуке

Comment: FILE = "result.csv"
file = open("Links.csv","r")